# Can 追求 function as a noun?

Tags: usage, word

I stumbled upon a bunch of example sentences [at YouDao](https://youdao.com/result?word=lj%3A%E7%9A%84%E8%BF%BD%E6%B1%82&lang=en) wherein 追求 is used as a noun:

> 对金钱的**追求**支配着他的生活。
> 我对崭新未来的**追求**未曾犹豫过。
> 谁能否认他们的**追求**是合理的呢？

I'm skeptical.  I looked it up in 现代汉语词典, and it doesn't list 追求 as a noun, and my dictionaries in Pleco didn't list it either.  But there's more than one example with 追求 being used as a noun, so maybe it's possible.

**Question**: Can 追求 function as a noun?

In any case, it seems better to use 目标, 任务, 使命, etc.

Comment: I just wanted to say that many nouns can be used as verbs, and verbs as nouns.  The same goes for adverbs and adjectives.  Parts of speech in chinese are fairly fluid, with the right context and sentence structure they are very often changeable to other parts of speech.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it can be a noun. Although I am not a linguist, according to my experience, I used to see a lot of sentences using 追求 as a noun in many formal and informal scenarios. I just looked up a couple of 字典 and they don't list noun 追求. I don't know the perfect reason behind it, but I believe the most possible reason is, in Chinese, most of the meanings' verb version and noun version are the same word unlike English. For example, apply is a verb, application is the corresponding noun, but in Chinese, they are all 申请(or 应用 etc.). Therefore, the reason why 追求 was used as a noun may because of the evolution of language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is both a verb and a noun.

[image]

- 对金钱的追求支配着他的生活。- Direct toward the pursuit of money denominates his livelihood.
- 我对崭新未来的追求未曾犹豫过。- I've never hesitated in pursuit of a brand new future.
- 谁能否认他们的追求是合理的呢？- Who can deny their pursuit is reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

无尽的追求(endless striving)
周作人文化思想與審美追求 The cultural ideas and aesthetic pursuit of Zhou Zuoren